# Bootstrap tutorial

Tags: html, twitter, css-framework, bootstrap

I am a newbie :( Out of a mix of curiosity and a desire to live on the edge, I just downloaded Twitter's Bootstrap! I see many cool bells and whistles there! The problem is I don't know how to go about building the next Insane Web site! Can some good folks here hand-hold me on the way to finding some good Bootstrap tutorial? I hope I haven't really asked a real 'newbie' question.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap already have their own [getting started tutorial](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html) online which is great and some other [great tutorial can be found on tutsplus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/stepping-out-with-bootstrap-from-twitter/) and [AntJanus](http://antjanus.com/blog/web-development-tutorials/how-to-build-your-own-bootstrap-theme/.) You will need to know HTML5 and the rest should be pretty obvious how to use using their website as referencing on the grid positions. Additionally if you want to drive straight in and save time in integrating it into WordPress or another CMS then you can grab yourself the frameworks for various CMS engines, here is a few:

- [Bootstrap for WordPress](http://320press.com/wpbs/)
- [Joomla 3 uses a modified version of Bootstrap](http://www.joomla.org/)
- [Bootstrap for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/twitter_bootstrap)

Additional Useful Links

- [Bootstrap PSD](http://gui.repixdesign.com/#bootstrap)
- [Inline Bootstrap Editing](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/)
- [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For absolute Beginners, you can have a look at this video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVFQc0iGFwU (up to 11 parts).